# Matlab: select consecutive values that are lower than a specific value

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a matrix of size 365x4 (since it is daily data). I need to select those consecutive values from the first column that are lower than a specific value (in this case 10) to analyse it afterwards.

In Matlab, how can I define find not only those that lower than 10, but also part of at least 2 consecutive values lower than 10?

Current code:

```
bad_consecutive_radiation_days=disp(find(average_day_radiati‌​on(:,1)<10 &~ diff(average_day_radiation(:,1))<10));
```

Comment: How many must be consecutive? You want the first consecutive set or all groups containing consecutive data? What code have you tried?

Comment: find the index of those lower than 10 and then create the consecutive indexes, and at last index your data to get result

Comment: Also, do you have the Image Processing Toolbox? There is a quick and, as far as I can tell, robust way of doing it using some functions in the Image Processing Toolbox.

Comment: Hi @Wolfie Well from 2 data onwards, basically. I just need to see how many consecutive they are. I tried to use with the command find and something like this, but I know is completely wrong: bad_consecutive_radiation_days=disp(find(average_day_radiation(:,1)<10 &~ diff(average_day_radiation(:,1))<10));

Comment: @GameOfThrows thanks! with that at the end will I get the matrix only with those consecutive values?

Comment: Now I tried with a function I downloaded from Matlab called Runlength and get the results, but not with the other columns only with the column where I need to select those consecutives values (Not sure if I am explaining myself correctly): average_day=average_day_radiation(:,1);
[B, N]   = RunLength(average_day < 10);
B(N < 2) = false;
mask     = RunLength(B, N);
Result   = average_day_radiation(mask);

Comment: Hey @GameOfThrows I tried what you said with this, but I need to get the matrix only with those consecutive indices. Could you please give me a hint? Thanks! p=find(average_day_radiation(:,1)<10);
q=find(diff(p)==1);

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, using a combination of logical indexing and the `diff` function. See comments for details

```
% Test data (column vector of values greater or less than 10)
mydata = [10, 9, 9, 10, 9, 10, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 10]';
% Test for values less than 10
lowvalues = mydata(:,1) < 10;
% Get differences of test, for consecutive logic
consec = [0; diff(lowvalues)];
% Apply logic for more than 1 consecutive "lowvalues" element being true consecutively
output = [(consec(1:end-1) == 1 & consec(2:end) == 0) | ...
          (consec(1:end-1) == 0 & consec(2:end) == 0 & lowvalues(1:end-1) == 1) | ... 
          (consec(1:end-1) == 0 & consec(2:end) == -1); false]
% First test:  elements at start of consectutive list
% Second test: elements in the middle of consecutive list, which are low values
% Third test:  elements at the end of the consecutive list
```

Result:

```
% Test data and output:
mydata = [10,  9,  9, 10,  9, 10,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10,  9,  9, 10]'
output = [ 0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0]'
```

As you can see, the lone 9 is not seen as within a consecutive group, and all the grouped 9s are. You can get the indices using `find(output)`.

You can extract only the desired data using

```
desireddata = mydata(output);
% result: [9,9,9,9,9,9,9], the elements 2,3,7,8,9,13,14 from mydata
```

---

Edit:

To get the *rows* from a matrix satisfying this, just change the `desireddata` statement. That is, with `mydata` above being replaced by the column you want to test for consecutive values.

```
% Take the consecutive-value rows and all of the columns from a matrix
myConsecutiveValuesMatrix = myWholeMatrix(output, :)
```

Comment: Thanks @Wolfie! An additional question is this possible to be done for a matrix? I mean one column is where I need to get these consecutives values, but an the end I will need the matrix with the corresponding columns as well.

Comment: Hey! I tried it yesterday evening and it only took me the column and also included in the answer some values that are not consecutives.... I will try it again and I wil let you know!

Comment: If you could isolate a small example of data where it picks out non consecutive values, I might be able to fix something in the code

Comment: How should post the isolated sample here? Sorry for not answering before. It has been quite hectic around here

Comment: Try to reproduce your issue with a small matrix, say 10x10, and then add that data as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a clue from image processing world. First remove ones from input vector if they aren't followed by ones. Repeat N-1 such steps. Then perform N-1 steps of adding ones if they are preceded by ones. 
This approach is nice as it is trivial to extend from 2 values to say 5 just by changing N.

So:

```
lowvals = data < 10;
lowvals(end+1) = false; % Make fictional last point which is false to avoid edge checks.
N = 2; % in your case when you want numbers where at least 2 are above.
for i = 1 : N-1
   lowvals(1:end-1) = lowvals(1:end-1) & lowvals(2:end);
end
for i = 1 : N-1
   lowvals(2:end) = lowvals(2:end) | lowvals(1:end-1);
end
% At this point, lowvals will have filtered indices with that extra fictional value. Remove it.
lowvals = lowvals(1:end-1);
```

This code can be optimized a bit by moving this setting of fictional last point before the setting of other points (to avoid extension of array), but I believe it is clearer this way.